# Survive Mac address of client after routing

Tags: routing, router, arp, mac-address

I am developing an application in which it is very important that I can know the mac address of the client hitting the server.

- Clients are connected to `wifi router (W)`.
- Multiple `wifi routers (W)` are connected to a `switch (SW)`.
- A `server (SE)` is connected to the `switch (SW)` which acts as internet gateway for all the `wifi routers (W)`.
- The application I am developing is hosted on the `server (SE)`.

After multiple clients have made the requests, I check `arp -a` to get the mac address.

What I want is, in `arp cache` each client IP should be associated with its mac address.

I know that client mac doesn't survive the routing. But is there any way that I can configure the router such that mac address survives the routing?

Comment: You cannot do it per the normal TCP/IP protocol. You need to get a side channel to obtain it, either with an agent, or getting it directly from the infra-structure. Or do way with the requirement of knowing the MAC, and using locally installed X.509 certs as an alternative, for instance.

Comment: Or with IPv6 everywhere you could embed the MAC into the v6 addresses used.

Comment: Locking in applications to host parameters like mac/network addresses is a bad thing.